# I boiled sliced yellow squash with ravioli, and it turned bluish-green -- why?

Tags: squash

Boiled cheese ravioli for 10 minutes.  Added sliced yellow squash for the last 3 minutes.  Nothing else in the pot but boiling water, not even salt.  It looked fine cooking but after I drained everything in the colander, the squash rind stayed yellow but the flesh turned bluish-green on most pieces.  Not all pieces though.  It tastes the same as usual.  [image]The color is freaky.  Why did this happen?

Comment: possibly related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40616/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/77839/67

Comment: Note that it's definitely possible to get at least a little bit of this color just from cooking in a pan, so it's probably not too specific to any particulars of this question.

Comment: As the suggested answer will tell, your question needs additional information: what did you cook the ingredienst in (material)? Please add that.

Comment: Do you use iodized salt, and did you salt the pasta water? Iodine reacts to starch and turns blue.

Comment: Please add a photo?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the same reason why garlic turns blue sometimes when you cook it.
http://www.foodsafetysite.com/consumers/faq/?m_knowledgebase_article=14

its a reaction with sulfur + copper which can naturally occur in foods.

Answer (score 1):

It's cucumber mosaic virus. It is still edible, just makes the food look less desirable and therefore not as marketable. Producers try to avoid/prevent it for that reason. But it is still fine and edible.